# How to send hero card from bot framework to WhatsApp by Twilio WhatsApp API

Tags: twilio, botframework, whatsapp, twilio-api

I'm currently using Twilio WhatsApp API and Bot Framework Direct Line channel to try integrating my chatbot to WhatsApp.

Since my chatbot conversation is guided, a lot of PromptDialog.Choices messages are used (which is a hero cards). Is there a way to send these messages as their expected form (meaning with buttons for clicking) to Whatsapp using Twilio WhatsApp API ?

Comment: There is no documentation I could find to check if the hero cards are supported on the WhatsApp Api through Twillio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the Twilio API for WhatsApp doesn't support media. This is being developed.

However, the [WhatsApp API itself](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages) doesn't support the concept of a hero card or buttons for responding to messages.

Comment: Thanks for the information. For the statement "Currently the Twilio API for WhatsApp doesn't support media" is that also means that sending media / attachments to Twilio WhatsApp Number is also not supported ?

Comment: I just tested this, the body of the message will come through, but not the media. As I said though, the team is working on it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. The text in the hero card can be rendered as a text message. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this feature still not available?

Comment: You can now send images using the Twilio API for WhatsApp, and the WhatsApp API supports buttons too. Check the Twilio docs for all the latest!