# Bot framework hero card or image in WhatsApp bot

Tags: node.js, twilio, botframework, whatsapp

We have a WhatsApp bot developed using bot framework and Twilio. Hero card is not displaying in out WhatsApp bot. But I have seen some bots which displays images and button inside the WhatsApp bot. Can someone help me how to implement card in WhatsApp bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send hero card from bot framework to WhatsApp by Twilio WhatsApp API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624560/how-to-send-hero-card-from-bot-framework-to-whatsapp-by-twilio-whatsapp-api)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#card-support-by-channel