# Bot Composer: Adaptive/Hero Cards not rendering on Whats App

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

Had created a bot using Bot composer tool and using Twilio adapter to connect bot with WhatsApp.

I am trying to send response from bot using HeroCard and Adaptive Card . I am following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-send-cards?tabs=v1x) which is perfectly working in Emulator but not in wats app.

HeroCard, Adaptive Card are displaying in emulator.

Does wats app channel support responsive cards?

Comment: Please refer to this table about the [cards support by channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#card-support-by-channel) & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624560/how-to-send-hero-card-from-bot-framework-to-whatsapp-by-twilio-whatsapp-api

Answer (score 0):

As per the link shared by ranusharao [in MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#card-support-by-channel)

There is no support for Whatsapp channel yet.